Polars dataframe: how to efficiently aggregate over many non-disjoint groups
I have a dataframe with columns x, y, c_1, c2, ..., c_K, where K is somewhat large (K ≈ 1000 or 2000).
Each of the columns c_i is boolean column, and I'd like to compute an aggregation f(x, y) over rows where where c_i is True.  (For example, f(x,y) = x.sum() * y.sum().)
One way to do this is:
ds.select([
    f(pl.col("x").filter(pl.col(f"c_{i+1}"), pl.col("y").filter(pl.col(f"c_{i+1}"))
    for i in range(K)
])

In my problem, the number K is large, and the above query seems somewhat inefficient (filtering is done twice).

What is the recommended/most efficient/most elegant way of accomplishing this?


EDIT.
Here is a runnable example (code at bottom), as well as some timings corresponding to @Hericks's answer below. TLDR: Method 1 as proposed is the current best.





Wall time




1
repeated filters
409ms


2
pl.concat
29.6s (≈70x slower)


2*
pl.concat, lazy
1.27s (3x slower)


3
unpivot with agg
1min 17s


3*
unpivot with agg, lazy
1min 17s (same as 3)



import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()

def f(x,y):
    return x.sum() * y.sum()

N = 2_000_000
K = 1000
dat = dict()
dat["x"] = np.random.randn(N)
dat["y"] = np.random.randn(N)
for i in range(K):
    dat[f"c_{i+1}"] = rng.choice(2, N).astype(np.bool_)

tmpds = pl.DataFrame(dat)


## Method 1
tmpds.select([
    f(
        pl.col("x").filter(pl.col(f"c_{i+1}")),
        pl.col("y").filter(pl.col(f"c_{i+1}")))
    .alias(f"f_{i+1}") for i in range(K)
])

## Method 2
pl.concat([
    tmpds.filter(pl.col(f"c_{i+1}")).select(f(pl.col("x"), pl.col("y")).alias(f"f_{i+1}"))
    for i in range(K)
], how="horizontal")

## Method 2*
pl.concat([
    tmpds.lazy().filter(pl.col(f"c_{i+1}")).select(f(pl.col("x"), pl.col("y")).alias(f"f_{i+1}")).collect()
    for i in range(K)
], how="horizontal")

## Method 3
(
    tmpds
    .unpivot(on=cs.starts_with("c"), index=["x", "y"])
    .filter("value")
    .group_by("variable")
    .agg(
        f(pl.col("x"), pl.col("y"))
    )
)

##Method 3*
(
    tmpds
    .lazy()
    .unpivot(on=cs.starts_with("c"), index=["x", "y"])
    .filter("value")
    .group_by("variable", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        f(pl.col("x"), pl.col("y"))
    )
    .collect()
)


In general, I would not think that multiple filters are inefficient in polars.  To verify this, I benchmarked three different approaches:
1. Generator of expressions with 2 filters
This approach was proposed in the question.
df.select(
    (
        pl.col("x").filter(f"c_{i+1}").sum()
        * pl.col("y").filter(f"c_{i+1}").sum()
    ).alias(f"c_{i}")
    for i in range(K)
)

2. Concatenating dataframes created using single filter
This approach was proposed by @roman. Again, a python generator is used to create the dataframes.
pl.concat(
    [
        (
            df
            .filter(pl.col(f"c_{i+1}"))
            .select((pl.col("x").sum() * pl.col("y").sum()).alias(f"c_{i+1}"))
        )
        for i in range(K)
    ],
    how="horizontal"
)

3. Unpivot + single filter + group by / agg
I thought this approach was nice as it doesn't rely on standard python generator expressions and doesn't use f-strings to create column names.
import polars.selectors as cs

(
    df
    .unpivot(on=cs.starts_with("c"), index=["x", "y"])
    .filter("value")
    .group_by("variable", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.col("x").sum() * pl.col("y").sum()
    )
)

The results for f(x, y) = x.sum() * y.sum() on a dataframe with n = 5000 rows and K = 1000 c_i-columns` are as follows. The results confirm the initial impression.





Runtime




1
repeated filters
16.7ms


2
pl.concat
4150ms


3
unpivot with agg
40.9ms




Thanks! Indeed the repeated filters (method #1, as in the question post) is by far the most efficient.  (I will also update the question with my own timings.)

(Will let question sit for a while more before accepting.)

Not sure if it will be more efficient (Polars is pretty good at optimizing), but you can also filter DataFrame instead. Your function is aggregating into one row/one column anyway, you can concat() these results horizontally.
pl.concat(
    [df.filter(pl.col(f"c_{i+1}")).select(f(pl.col.x, pl.col.y)) for i in range(K)],
    how="horizontal"
)

If there's more known about possible functions you need to be able to execute? For example, are they always aggregates?

Thanks! Adding a .lazy() and .collect() pair to each df in the filter will also significantly speed up performance, since the intermediate df will not need to be realized. So my edited question's Method 2*.
